# How do I get all alerts from azure monitor via JAVA

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

I just need to get all alerts from Azure monitor using JAVA, Is there any way to get all Alerts via Rest API or SDK?

Comment: sure why not? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#how-to-call-azure-rest-apis-with-curl making a GET request using JAVA.

Comment: it helps also: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/06/23/authenticating-azure-resource-management-rest-api-requests-using-java/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/alertsmanagement/alerts/getall) could help you, this API could get all existing alerts,it provides many Parameters to filter the alerts.

And if this could not meet your needs, you also could choose other [APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/rest/api/monitor/alertsmanagement/alerts#operations) you want.

If you still have other questions, please let me know.